# HTML/JS - Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

In the past the systems I have built have used the jQuery datepicker and it worked great. Recently I decided to move to using twitter bootstrap for my designs and quickly learned that it doesn't like the jQuery UI.

I'm trying to get http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ working at the moment.

I've viewed all the similar questions and their solutions, but cannot seem to find any that directly apply to my situation.

The JavaScript:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="../images/favicon.ico">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinybox.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#date').datepicker();
    function delete(id)  
        {
        var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")
            if (r==true)
            {
                location.href = "delete.php?id=" + id;
            }
        }
    function single(id)
        {
            TINY.box.show({iframe:'../view.php?id=' + id,boxid:'frameless',width:550,height:170,fixed:false,maskid:'bluemask',maskopacity:40,closejs:function(){closeJS()}})
        }
</script>
```

The html:

```
<input name="date" class="src_date" type="textarea" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" id="date" required>
```

I have also tried with the JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is often the result of a JS conflict, where another plugin is causing the $ variable to behave abnormally. To get around this just wrap your function with jQuery:

```
$('#date').datepicker();
```

=>

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#date").datepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});
});
```

also your `dateFormat` parameters are for jQuery UI, for bootstrap datepicker just use `format` as I have used in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

As if this is not working:

```
$(function() {
   $("#date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});
});
```

then it seems to be that you have to load your jQuery library first then other libs:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinybox.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately making this change has not fixed the issue. However when checking that none of my scripts are returning a 404 in console, i noticed an error referring to the datepicker function in your answer (Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker')

Answer (score 0):

Load `tinybox` after `jquery` and check you have downloaded `datepicker` and `tinybox` js like,

Otherwise try this,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/tinybox.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   $("#date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});
});
</script>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/sefosuye/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately making this change has not fixed the issue. However when checking that none of my scripts are returning a 404 in console, i noticed an error referring to the datepicker function in your answer (Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker')

Comment: I replaced my scripts with those you used for the demo including the ordering, however nothing happens when clicking into the date field. When viewing the console it gives: **GET http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js 404 (Not Found)** along with the previous console error

Comment: You can find it in my original post, with the date function (which you used in example) instead of the **$('#date').datepicker();**